# What's it called when you do a swipe gesture and the swipe continues after the end of gesture

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, terminology, gesture

Just terminology question. What's the official name of that effect when you make a swipe gesture on Android or iOS and the content continues to move after the gesture ended slowly stopping.

Comment: Do you mean fling?

Comment: @pawel I don't know what it's called. That's why I'm asking. but it might be close enough.